# Создание объектов в Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку создавался объект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Btn As Button = New Button
Me.Controls.Add(Btn)
```

Comment: А если обект браузер

Comment: Ну, меняете **`Button`** на **`WebBrowser`**

Comment: Также, не забудьте поставить размер и адрес перед выводом.